# Как подключить автозавершение кода Unity в vs code?

Tags: unity3d, visual-studio-code

Никак не могу включить автозавершение кода, в vs code под Unity, скачал все расширения(см. картинку) ..список брал [тут](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity) и даже поставил [вот этот плагин](https://github.com/dotBunny/VSCode/blob/master/Plugins/Editor/VSCode.cs) (настроил), но не помогло... Работаю на linux, поэтому скачать vs не предлагайте.

> ? Есть ли замена vs, с рабочим автозавершением кода, или есть способ добавить его в vs code?

[image: расширения]

Comment: "Работаю на linux, поэтому скачать vs не предлагайте."

Comment: vs и vs code - разные вещи.

Comment: Чел удалил комент, но пусть это будет тут :D